# How do I prevent a cumbersome query from timing out in Postgrex?

Tags: elixir, ecto, postgrex

I'm running a query and loading the results into a Stream using Postgrex, like so:

```
{:ok, host_pid} = Postgrex.start_link(hostname: "somewhere.hostname.io", username: "myuser", password: "mypass", database: "mydb")

Postgrex.transaction(host_pid, fn(conn) ->
    # do query that takes 5 seconds
    # with timeout set to be really big
    query = Postgrex.prepare!(conn, "", "SELECT pg_sleep(5)", timeout: 50_000)
    stream = Postgrex.stream(conn, query)
    result_to_iodata = fn(%Postgrex.Result{rows: rows}) -> format_query_result(rows) end
    Enum.into(stream, File.stream!("eg"), result_to_iodata)
end)
```

But I get the following error:

```
localhost$ mix run lib/MyPostgrexScript.exs 
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) connection not available and request was dropped 
from queue after 2950ms. You can configure how long requests wait in the queue 
using :queue_target and :queue_interval. See DBConnection.start_link/2 for more information
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:836: DBConnection.transaction/3
    lib/MyPostgrexScript.exs:3: MyPostgrexModule.sleep/0
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:147: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/5
```

Since I want to do cumbersome queries which will certainly require more than 2950ms to run, I am wondering how I configure Postgrex to let my query take more time. I read about the `:timeout` option at https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.html#transaction/3 but I'm not sure to how include it, or whether it's what I'm looking for.

Any guidance is immensely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read about the :timeout option at
>   https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.html#transaction/3 but I'm not
>   sure to how include it,

Like this (see the last line):

```
Postgrex.transaction(
    host_pid,

    fn(conn) ->
        # do query that takes 5 seconds
        # with timeout set to be really big
        query = Postgrex.prepare!(conn, "", "SELECT pg_sleep(5)", timeout: 50_000)
        stream = Postgrex.stream(conn, query)
        result_to_iodata = fn(%Postgrex.Result{rows: rows}) ->
                                 format_query_result(rows) 
                           end
        Enum.into(stream, File.stream!("eg"), result_to_iodata)
    end,

    timeout: 30_000  #30 seconds
)
```

Whenever the elixir docs define a function like this:

```
func_name(arg1, ...argN, opts \\ [] )
```

`opts` is a keyword list, e.g:

```
[{:a, 1}, {:b, 2}]
```

However, if a keyword list is the last argument in a function call, the keyword list can be written like this:

```
func(arg1, arg2, a: 1, b: 2)
```

and the function definition will receive the *three* arguments

```
arg1, arg2, [{:a, 1}, {:b, 2}]
```

In any case, the default for :timeout is:

```
:timeout - Transaction timeout (default: 15000);
```

and the error says:

> connection not available and request was dropped  from queue after
>   2950ms

Because `2950 < 15000` it doesn't seem like the :timeout value is the source of the error.

The error message continues:

> connection not available.... 
>   You can configure how long requests wait in the queue  using
>   :queue_target and :queue_interval. See DBConnection.start_link/2 for
>   more information

[This](https://elixirforum.com/t/dbconnection-error/21478) explains how to configure those timeouts:

> In `config/<env>.exs` (where `<env>` is dev, test, or prod):
>
> ```
> config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
>   adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
>   pool_size: 10,
>   migration_timestamps: [type: :utc_datetime_usec],
>   migration_lock: nil,
>   queue_target: 5000
> ```
>
> Is what we had to do recently due to increased number of errors in
>   production.

[Also](https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/DBConnection.html#start_link/2-queue-config),

> Handling requests is done through a queue. When DBConnection is
>   started, there are two relevant options to control the queue:
>
> ```
> :queue_target in milliseconds, defaults to 50ms
> :queue_interval in milliseconds, defaults to 1000ms
> ```
>
> Our goal is to wait at most :queue_target for a connection. If all
>   connections checked out during a :queue_interval takes more than
>   :queue_target, then we double the :queue_target. If checking out
>   connections take longer than the new target, then we start dropping
>   messages.
>
> For example, by default our target is 50ms. If all connections
>   checkouts take longer than 50ms for a whole second, we double the
>   target to 100ms and we start dropping messages if the time to checkout
>   goes above the new limit.
>
> This allows us to better plan for overloads as we can refuse requests
>   before they are sent to the database, which would otherwise increase
>   the burden on the database, making the overload worse.

But, if you haven't touched those defaults, then I wonder why you are seeing 
`2950ms` in the error message and not something closer to 50ms or 1000ms.

Comment: It turns out that pg_sleep doesn't even exist on Amazon Redshift (which is what I was connecting to). Although the error message insists that the error was in the transaction, I believe that the timeout was during the attempt to connect. But the bug went away on it's own so who knows. Nevertheless, fantastic answer, thanks for taking the time!